# Не отображаются текстуры на модели?

Tags: c++, opengl

Начал изучать OpenGL, и столкнулся с проблемой, что текстуры на модели не отображается, сплошной чёрный цвет. Полностью скопировал код из руководства, но результат тот же.

В чём может быть проблема?

Основной код:

```
#include<filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
//------------------------------

#include<iostream>
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<stb/stb_image.h>
#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include"Texture.h"
#include"shaderClass.h"
#include"VAO.h"
#include"VBO.h"
#include"EBO.h"


const unsigned int width = 800;
const unsigned int height = 800;


// Vertices coordinates
GLfloat vertices[] =
{ //     COORDINATES     /        COLORS      /   TexCoord  //
    -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.5f,     0.83f, 0.70f, 0.44f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f,     0.83f, 0.70f, 0.44f,    5.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f,     0.83f, 0.70f, 0.44f,    0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, 0.0f,  0.5f,     0.83f, 0.70f, 0.44f,    5.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f, 0.8f,  0.0f,     0.92f, 0.86f, 0.76f,    2.5f, 5.0f
};

// Indices for vertices order
GLuint indices[] =
{
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 2, 3,
    0, 1, 4,
    1, 2, 4,
    2, 3, 4,
    3, 0, 4
};



int main()
{
    // Initialize GLFW
    glfwInit();

    // Tell GLFW what version of OpenGL we are using 
    // In this case we are using OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    // Tell GLFW we are using the CORE profile
    // So that means we only have the modern functions
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Create a GLFWwindow object of 800 by 800 pixels, naming it "YoutubeOpenGL"
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "konec", NULL, NULL);
    // Error check if the window fails to create
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    // Introduce the window into the current context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //Load GLAD so it configures OpenGL
    gladLoadGL();
    // Specify the viewport of OpenGL in the Window
    // In this case the viewport goes from x = 0, y = 0, to x = 800, y = 800
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);



    // Generates Shader object using shaders default.vert and default.frag
    Shader shaderProgram("default.vert", "default.frag");



    // Generates Vertex Array Object and binds it
    VAO VAO1;
    VAO1.Bind();

    // Generates Vertex Buffer Object and links it to vertices
    VBO VBO1(vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    // Generates Element Buffer Object and links it to indices
    EBO EBO1(indices, sizeof(indices));

    // Links VBO attributes such as coordinates and colors to VAO
    VAO1.LinkAttrib(VBO1, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    VAO1.LinkAttrib(VBO1, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    VAO1.LinkAttrib(VBO1, 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
    // Unbind all to prevent accidentally modifying them
    VAO1.Unbind();
    VBO1.Unbind();
    EBO1.Unbind();

    // Gets ID of uniform called "scale"
    GLuint uniID = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "scale");

    /*
    * I'm doing this relative path thing in order to centralize all the resources into one folder and not
    * duplicate them between tutorial folders. You can just copy paste the resources from the 'Resources'
    * folder and then give a relative path from this folder to whatever resource you want to get to.
    * Also note that this requires C++17, so go to Project Properties, C/C++, Language, and select C++17
    */
    std::string parentDir = (fs::current_path().fs::path::parent_path()).string();
    std::string texPath = "/Resources/1/";

    // Texture
    Texture brickTex((parentDir + texPath + "brick.png").c_str(), GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
    brickTex.texUnit(shaderProgram, "tex0", 0);

    // Original code from the tutorial
    /*Texture brickTex("brick.png", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
    brickTex.texUnit(shaderProgram, "tex0", 0);*/

    // Variables that help the rotation of the pyramid
    float rotation = 0.0f;
    double prevTime = glfwGetTime();

    // Enables the Depth Buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Main while loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Specify the color of the background
        glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
        // Clean the back buffer and depth buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Tell OpenGL which Shader Program we want to use
        shaderProgram.Activate();

        // Simple timer
        double crntTime = glfwGetTime();
        if (crntTime - prevTime >= 1 / 60)
        {
            rotation += 0.5f;
            prevTime = crntTime;
        }

        // Initializes matrices so they are not the null matrix
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 proj = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        // Assigns different transformations to each matrix
        model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(rotation), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, -0.5f, -2.0f));
        proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)width / height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

        // Outputs the matrices into the Vertex Shader
        int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "model");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        int projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.ID, "proj");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));

        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Assigns a value to the uniform; NOTE: Must always be done after activating the Shader Program
        glUniform1f(uniID, 0.5f);
        // Binds texture so that is appears in rendering
        brickTex.Bind();
        // Bind the VAO so OpenGL knows to use it
        VAO1.Bind();
        // Draw primitives, number of indices, datatype of indices, index of indices
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(int), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        // Swap the back buffer with the front buffer
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        // Take care of all GLFW events
        glfwPollEvents();
    }



    // Delete all the objects we've created
    VAO1.Delete();
    VBO1.Delete();
    EBO1.Delete();
    brickTex.Delete();
    shaderProgram.Delete();
    // Delete window before ending the program
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    // Terminate GLFW before ending the program
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Код для текстур:

```
#include"Texture.h"

Texture::Texture(const char* image, GLenum texType, GLenum slot, GLenum format, GLenum pixelType)
{
    // Assigns the type of the texture ot the texture object
    type = texType;

    // Stores the width, height, and the number of color channels of the image
    int widthImg, heightImg, numColCh;
    // Flips the image so it appears right side up
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    // Reads the image from a file and stores it in bytes
    unsigned char* bytes = stbi_load(image, &widthImg, &heightImg, &numColCh, 0);

    // Generates an OpenGL texture object
    glGenTextures(1, &ID);
    // Assigns the texture to a Texture Unit
    glActiveTexture(slot);
    glBindTexture(texType, ID);

    // Configures the type of algorithm that is used to make the image smaller or bigger
    glTexParameteri(texType, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(texType, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    // Configures the way the texture repeats (if it does at all)
    glTexParameteri(texType, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(texType, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    // Extra lines in case you choose to use GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER
    // float flatColor[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    // glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, flatColor);

    // Assigns the image to the OpenGL Texture object
    glTexImage2D(texType, 0, GL_RGBA, widthImg, heightImg, 0, format, pixelType, bytes);
    // Generates MipMaps
    glGenerateMipmap(texType);

    // Deletes the image data as it is already in the OpenGL Texture object
    stbi_image_free(bytes);

    // Unbinds the OpenGL Texture object so that it can't accidentally be modified
    glBindTexture(texType, 0);
}

void Texture::texUnit(Shader& shader, const char* uniform, GLuint unit)
{
    // Gets the location of the uniform
    GLuint texUni = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, uniform);
    // Shader needs to be activated before changing the value of a uniform
    shader.Activate();
    // Sets the value of the uniform
    glUniform1i(texUni, unit);
}

void Texture::Bind()
{
    glBindTexture(type, ID);
}

void Texture::Unbind()
{
    glBindTexture(type, 0);
}

void Texture::Delete()
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &ID);
}
```

И ещё:

```
#ifndef TEXTURE_CLASS_H
#define TEXTURE_CLASS_H

#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<stb/stb_image.h>

#include"shaderClass.h"

class Texture
{
public:
    GLuint ID;
    GLenum type;
    Texture(const char* image, GLenum texType, GLenum slot, GLenum format, GLenum pixelType);

    // Assigns a texture unit to a texture
    void texUnit(Shader& shader, const char* uniform, GLuint unit);
    // Binds a texture
    void Bind();
    // Unbinds a texture
    void Unbind();
    // Deletes a texture
    void Delete();
};
#endif
```

Шейдеры:

VAO

```
#include"VAO.h"

// Constructor that generates a VAO ID
VAO::VAO()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &ID);
}

// Links a VBO Attribute such as a position or color to the VAO
void VAO::LinkAttrib(VBO& VBO, GLuint layout, GLuint numComponents, GLenum type, GLsizeiptr stride, void* offset)
{
    VBO.Bind();
    glVertexAttribPointer(layout, numComponents, type, GL_FALSE, stride, offset);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(layout);
    VBO.Unbind();
}

// Binds the VAO
void VAO::Bind()
{
    glBindVertexArray(ID);
}

// Unbinds the VAO
void VAO::Unbind()
{
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

// Deletes the VAO
void VAO::Delete()
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &ID);
}





#ifndef VAO_CLASS_H
#define VAO_CLASS_H

#include<glad/glad.h>
#include"VBO.h"

class VAO
{
public:
    // ID reference for the Vertex Array Object
    GLuint ID;
    // Constructor that generates a VAO ID
    VAO();

    // Links a VBO Attribute such as a position or color to the VAO
    void LinkAttrib(VBO& VBO, GLuint layout, GLuint numComponents, GLenum type, GLsizeiptr stride, void* offset);
    // Binds the VAO
    void Bind();
    // Unbinds the VAO
    void Unbind();
    // Deletes the VAO
    void Delete();
};

#endif
```

VBO

```
#include"VBO.h"

// Constructor that generates a Vertex Buffer Object and links it to vertices
VBO::VBO(GLfloat* vertices, GLsizeiptr size)
{
    glGenBuffers(1, &ID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

// Binds the VBO
void VBO::Bind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ID);
}

// Unbinds the VBO
void VBO::Unbind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

// Deletes the VBO
void VBO::Delete()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ID);
}






#ifndef VBO_CLASS_H
#define VBO_CLASS_H

#include<glad/glad.h>

class VBO
{
public:
    // Reference ID of the Vertex Buffer Object
    GLuint ID;
    // Constructor that generates a Vertex Buffer Object and links it to vertices
    VBO(GLfloat* vertices, GLsizeiptr size);

    // Binds the VBO
    void Bind();
    // Unbinds the VBO
    void Unbind();
    // Deletes the VBO
    void Delete();
};

#endif
```

Shaderclass:

```
#include"shaderClass.h"

// Reads a text file and outputs a string with everything in the text file
std::string get_file_contents(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (in)
    {
        std::string contents;
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        contents.resize(in.tellg());
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        in.read(&contents[0], contents.size());
        in.close();
        return(contents);
    }
    throw(errno);
}

// Constructor that build the Shader Program from 2 different shaders
Shader::Shader(const char* vertexFile, const char* fragmentFile)
{
    // Read vertexFile and fragmentFile and store the strings
    std::string vertexCode = get_file_contents(vertexFile);
    std::string fragmentCode = get_file_contents(fragmentFile);

    // Convert the shader source strings into character arrays
    const char* vertexSource = vertexCode.c_str();
    const char* fragmentSource = fragmentCode.c_str();

    // Create Vertex Shader Object and get its reference
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    // Attach Vertex Shader source to the Vertex Shader Object
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    // Compile the Vertex Shader into machine code
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    // Checks if Shader compiled succesfully
    compileErrors(vertexShader, "VERTEX");

    // Create Fragment Shader Object and get its reference
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    // Attach Fragment Shader source to the Fragment Shader Object
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    // Compile the Vertex Shader into machine code
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    // Checks if Shader compiled succesfully
    compileErrors(fragmentShader, "FRAGMENT");

    // Create Shader Program Object and get its reference
    ID = glCreateProgram();
    // Attach the Vertex and Fragment Shaders to the Shader Program
    glAttachShader(ID, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(ID, fragmentShader);
    // Wrap-up/Link all the shaders together into the Shader Program
    glLinkProgram(ID);
    // Checks if Shaders linked succesfully
    compileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");

    // Delete the now useless Vertex and Fragment Shader objects
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

}

// Activates the Shader Program
void Shader::Activate()
{
    glUseProgram(ID);
}

// Deletes the Shader Program
void Shader::Delete()
{
    glDeleteProgram(ID);
}

// Checks if the different Shaders have compiled properly
void Shader::compileErrors(unsigned int shader, const char* type)
{
    // Stores status of compilation
    GLint hasCompiled;
    // Character array to store error message in
    char infoLog[1024];
    if (type != "PROGRAM")
    {
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &hasCompiled);
        if (hasCompiled == GL_FALSE)
        {
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR for:" << type << "\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &hasCompiled);
        if (hasCompiled == GL_FALSE)
        {
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
            std::cout << "SHADER_LINKING_ERROR for:" << type << "\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А может покажете весь код? Включая шейдеры. Причин может быть много сломанные шейдеры, ошибки внутри vao/ebo классов.

Comment: ¿Текстура-то у вас загружается? А то практически никакой обработки ошибок не видать.

Comment: Добавил шейдеры, но с ними вроде всё нормально, а как вообще проверить загрузку текстур? может ли быть проблема в дровах? насколько я знаю amd не очень хорошо работает с open gl.

Comment: Отлаживать пробовали? stbi_load возвращает указатель на массив или же nullptr?

Comment: ты в шейдерах uniform для текстуры создал?